# Foreach shows an extra empty echoed field

Tags: php, foreach

The following foreach loop shows an extra empty field. It has the html markup like in the foreach, but doesn't load anything from the database. There is no extra empty field in the database, I checked.

```
   //  content
    $content            = "SELECT * FROM `lb_content` WHERE catid = 13";
    $contentcon         = $conn->query($content);
    $contentcr          = array();
    while ($contentcr[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());

    foreach($contentcr as $content) 
    {

        $article_images = $content['images']; // Get image parameters of the article

        $pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart

        $contentje .= '<li class="job_listing">
        <a href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website/content.php?alias='.$content['alias'].'">
            <div class="location job_img">
                <img name="images" src="/_extern/website/cms/'.$pictures->{'image_intro'}.'" alt="" class="company_logo">
            </div>
            <div class="location boldfont">
                '.$content['title'].'
            </div>
            <div class="location specificaties">
            '.$content['introtext'].'
            </div>
            <div class="rating location">
                <div class="rating-stars">
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="location prijs">
                '.$content['metakey'].'
                <br>
                <div class="cursief">Vanaf 2 weken</div>
            </div>
            <div class="location">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buttonblock" onClick="location.href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website/content.php?page="'.$content['alias'].'">Nu huren</button>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>'; // Here
    }

echo $contentje;
```

Here is an image with the last working field and one extra. Where does the extra empty field come from?

This is part of the output of the array, as you can see array value '6' is empty.

```
            [5] => 

De ideale tijdelijke oplossing voor o.a.:
 Grotere kantoren
 Middelgrote winkels
 Serverruimtes
 Transformator ruimtes
 Feest tenten
 Meet- en regelkamers
 Hotels
 Restaurants
 Conferentieruimtes
 Laboratoria




Koelcapaciteit
    : 13,0 KW


Voeding
    : 230 V / 1 Fase / 50 Hz


Opgenomen vermogen per set
    : 4,82 kW


Nominale stroomsterkte
    : 3 x 7,6 A


Afzekerwaarde
    : 3 x 20 A T


Max. Leidinglengte
    : 40 m


Max. Hoogteverschil
    : 25 m


Koelleiding diameters
    : 3/8 - 3/4 inch


Voorzien van winterregeling
    : (-15 °C)



Binnenunit specificaties:




Luchtvolume
    : 900 / 1200 m3/h


Benodigde condensaansluiting
    : met ingebouwde condenspomp


Geluidsniveau (laag / hoog)*
    : 42 / 51 dB(A)


Gewicht
    : 50 kg


Afmetingen unit (HxBxD)
    : 1750 x 540 x 300 mm



Buitenunit specificaties:




Geluidsniveau
    : 58 dB(A)


Gewicht
    : 75 kg


Afmetingen (HxBxD)
    : 950 x 840 x 412 mm


Voeding
    : voorzien van een CEE stekker, 32A, 5-polig



            [fulltext] => 

De ideale tijdelijke oplossing voor o.a.:
 Grotere kantoren
 Middelgrote winkels
 Serverruimtes
 Transformator ruimtes
 Feest tenten
 Meet- en regelkamers
 Hotels
 Restaurants
 Conferentieruimtes
 Laboratoria




Koelcapaciteit
    : 13,0 KW


Voeding
    : 230 V / 1 Fase / 50 Hz


Opgenomen vermogen per set
    : 4,82 kW


Nominale stroomsterkte
    : 3 x 7,6 A


Afzekerwaarde
    : 3 x 20 A T


Max. Leidinglengte
    : 40 m


Max. Hoogteverschil
    : 25 m


Koelleiding diameters
    : 3/8 - 3/4 inch


Voorzien van winterregeling
    : (-15 °C)



Binnenunit specificaties:




Luchtvolume
    : 900 / 1200 m3/h


Benodigde condensaansluiting
    : met ingebouwde condenspomp


Geluidsniveau (laag / hoog)*
    : 42 / 51 dB(A)


Gewicht
    : 50 kg


Afmetingen unit (HxBxD)
    : 1750 x 540 x 300 mm



Buitenunit specificaties:




Geluidsniveau
    : 58 dB(A)


Gewicht
    : 75 kg


Afmetingen (HxBxD)
    : 950 x 840 x 412 mm


Voeding
    : voorzien van een CEE stekker, 32A, 5-polig



            [6] => 1
            [state] => 1
            [7] => 13
            [catid] => 13
            [8] => 2015-11-30 10:28:23
            [created] => 2015-11-30 10:28:23
            [9] => 361
            [created_by] => 361
            [10] => 
            [created_by_alias] => 
            [11] => 2015-12-08 13:14:13
            [modified] => 2015-12-08 13:14:13
            [12] => 361
            [modified_by] => 361
            [13] => 0
            [checked_out] => 0
            [14] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [15] => 2015-11-30 10:28:23
            [publish_up] => 2015-11-30 10:28:23
            [16] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [publish_down] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [17] => {"image_intro":"images\/website\/AELIA_30_45.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
            [images] => {"image_intro":"images\/website\/AELIA_30_45.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
            [18] => {"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
            [urls] => {"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
            [19] => {"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}
            [attribs] => {"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}
            [20] => 14
            [version] => 14
            [21] => 0
            [ordering] => 0
            [22] => € 195
            [metakey] => € 195
            [23] => 
            [metadesc] => 
            [24] => 1
            [access] => 1
            [25] => 0
            [hits] => 0
            [26] => {"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}
            [metadata] => {"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}
            [27] => 0
            [featured] => 0
            [28] => *
            [language] => *
            [29] => 
            [xreference] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [id] => 16
            [1] => 84
            [asset_id] => 84
            [2] => Aelia 55 (AL-55)
            [title] => Aelia 55 (AL-55)
            [3] => aelia-55-al-55
            [alias] => aelia-55-al-55
            [4] => 



Type
    : AL-55


Koelvermogen
    : 18,0 Kw


Afvoervermogen
    : Zuilkoeling staand model


Ruimtes tot
    : 520m3




            [introtext] => 



Type
    : AL-55


Koelvermogen
    : 18,0 Kw


Afvoervermogen
    : Zuilkoeling staand model


Ruimtes tot
    : 520m3




            [5] => 



            [fulltext] => 



            [6] => 1
            [state] => 1
            [7] => 13
            [catid] => 13
            [8] => 2015-11-30 10:38:11
            [created] => 2015-11-30 10:38:11
            [9] => 361
            [created_by] => 361
            [10] => 
            [created_by_alias] => 
            [11] => 2015-12-09 14:07:30
            [modified] => 2015-12-09 14:07:30
            [12] => 361
            [modified_by] => 361
            [13] => 361
            [checked_out] => 361
            [14] => 2015-12-09 14:07:30
            [checked_out_time] => 2015-12-09 14:07:30
            [15] => 2015-11-30 10:38:11
            [publish_up] => 2015-11-30 10:38:11
            [16] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [publish_down] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [17] => {"image_intro":"images\/website\/AELIA_55.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
            [images] => {"image_intro":"images\/website\/AELIA_55.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
            [18] => {"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
            [urls] => {"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
            [19] => {"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}
            [attribs] => {"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}
            [20] => 8
            [version] => 8
            [21] => 0
            [ordering] => 0
            [22] => € 235
            [metakey] => € 235
            [23] => 
            [metadesc] => 
            [24] => 1
            [access] => 1
            [25] => 0
            [hits] => 0
            [26] => {"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}
            [metadata] => {"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}
            [27] => 0
            [featured] => 0
            [28] => *
            [language] => *
            [29] => 
            [xreference] => 
        )

    [6] =>
```

Comment: Why not only `$contentcr = $contentcon->fetch_array()`?? No need for that extra loop then.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump` the array before the `foreach` to check what's inside the returned array?

Comment: @SvenvanZoelen I tried that, but it just shows all the correct array values.

Comment: @Sougata How do I do that with a while loop?

Comment: @Sougata I tried what you said, but now it only returns single characters, and way to many. Now it looks like this: https://i.gyazo.com/c2c6011f73ecb198cdd19f7692512220.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `while ($contentcr[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());` will keep making trips to the database result and put something into the array, regardless.

What you then have is the last array index in `$contentcr` effectively being FALSE, as it can no longer gather a result set.  Something is still returned, but not a result set.

Your array then looks something like:

```
$contentcr[0] = array(...);
$contentcr[1] = array(...);
$contentcr[n-1] = array(...);
$contentcr[n] = FALSE;
```

Which is why you always end up with an empty field.

You can better get round this by replacing your `foreach($contentcr as $content)` line with `while ($content = $contentcon->fetch_array())`.  This will stop when `$contentcon->fetch_array()` is false, and won't give you an empty field

Comment: Alright, I understand what you mean. But I always use a foreach for this, do you have an example how I can use a while loop and still iterate through all values? Because when I replace the foreach with the while code it stops outputting any results.